# This code is showing errors.What is wrong with this code?

Tags: java

```
File file = new File("D:/projects/tFile.txt") ;
        file.createNewFile();  //Unhandled exception type IOException
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file); //Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
        String s = "Cricket";
        byte []b = s.getBytes();
        fout.write(b);//Unhandled exception type IOException
        fout.close();// Unhandled exception type IOException
```

This is showing FileNotFound Exception and IoException.

Comment: When you have a question about errors, please make sure to include in your question whether the error is compile-time or runtime, what line the error occurs on, and the *complete* error text.

Comment: Did you bother to Google the errors to make an effort to understand what they are, why they are happening, and what some potential fixes might be?

Comment: Did you even read the error messages?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is asking you to handle the Exceptions that are being thrown from the methods that you have used.

Surround them in a try catch block.

```
public void method(){
        try {
            File file = new File("D:/projects/tFile.txt") ;
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
            String s = "IPL is very entertaining tournament";
            byte []b = s.getBytes();
            fout.write(b);;
            fout.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't really *fix* the issue.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: All this does is keep the exceptions from crashing the program. The exceptions are still thrown and the problem is not fixed. I therefore don't think that this is a valid answer.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile() Create new file throws IOException as per the Javadoc API. Will the code get compiled without adding exception handling?

Comment: Not sure what your point is. Your answer still doesn't address the actual problem.

Comment: I request you to try pasting the code in eclipse. I guess the errors mentioned in the question are compile time errors. Not runtime. Cause IOException and FileNotFoundException are the exact exceptions that are thrown with the above code.

Comment: Thanks Pavan, issue is fixed.

Comment: Those are both runtime exceptions. An exception, by definition, happens at runtime. @SsumitChaudhary This does not fix your issue. You have some sort of permissions issue that is just being covered up by this code.

Comment: I have a doubt, is it necessary to encapsulate the code in try catch block.As exceptions are being thrown implicitly.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/ Request you to go through that link and understand. I rest my case.

Comment: But if it is permission issue how it can be solved?

Comment: @SsumitChaudhary You can also add throws clause to your method definition. Let the calling method handle the exception.

Comment: Got it Pavan, thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

This is executed fine.Might be ur D:/projects is missing.
or may be due to exception

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("D:/Test/tFile.txt") ;
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
    String s = "IPL is very entertaining tournament";
    byte []b = s.getBytes();
    fout.write(b);;
    fout.close();
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: No, D:/projects is not missing.Path is correct.

Comment: Did you actually try putting this in eclipse. Will you be able to compile it?